# Android union query

Tags: android, group-by, union, android-contentprovider

I have the following problem:
I have a table called ***planing*** it has the following fields:

```
idplaning, month, year, shop, target, sales
```

so the table will contain info like this (ignoring the idplaning):

```
    month  year  shop       target  sales
-------------------------------------------
     1     2014  ShopName1  3534    122
     2     2014  ShopName1  2323    111
    ...
     12    2014  ShopName1  7865    328
     1     2014  ShopName2  4544    544
     2     2014  ShopName2  5675    642
    ...
     12    2014  ShopName2  4623    323
    ...
     1     2015  ShopName1  3534    122
     2     2015  ShopName1  2323    111
    ...
     12    2015  ShopName1  7865    328
    ... and so on
```

basically, the table contains the monthly targets and sales for each shop

I need to display in a Listview something like this:

```
shop          Ianuary February March ... November December
----------------------------------------------------------
ShopName1     3534    2323     235       3545     3355
...
ShopNamex     1527    7815     631       556      2754
```

in order to do that (in plain SQL) I can do a union like this:

```
select shop, sum(Ian), sum(Feb),sum(Mar), sum(Apr), sum(Mai), sum(Iun), sum(Iul), sum(Aug), sum(Sep), sum(Oct), sum(Noi), sum(Decu) from
(
    select shop,target as Ian, 0 as Feb, 0 as Mar, 0 as Apr, 0 as Mai, 0 as Iun, 0 as Iul, 0 as Aug, 0 as Sep, 0 as Oct, 0 as Noi, 0 as Decu from planing where year=2015 and month=1
    union
    ...
    select shop,0 as Ian, 0 as Feb, 0 as Mar, 0 as Apr, 0 as Mai, 0 as Iun, 0 as Iul, 0 as Aug, 0 as Sep, 0 as Oct, 0 as Noi, target as Decu from planing where year=2015 and month=12
) as tbl
group by shop
```

Now, my problem is: how can I do that using a SQLite Database ContentProvider in Android with the **query approach**?
I already have the Content provider built for various regular DB operations, and I use the *query* approach (instead of *rawquery*)

So I obtain a regular cursor (for my ***planing*** table) like this:

```
String[] col = {MyFirstProvider.RSLDTL_ID_ID,MyFirstProvider.RSLDTL_SHOP, MyFirstProvider.RSLDTL_MONTH, MyFirstProvider.RSLDTL_TARGET, MyFirstProvider.RSLDTL_SALES};
String where = "year=2015";
Cursor cur =  getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MyFirstProvider.CONTENT_URI_RSLDTL, col, where, null, null);
```

My problem: How can I obtain a cursor for my UNION-Groupped query using the query approach (**not the rawquery**)

Please answer with code. Thank you

**EDIT**
My ContentProvider looks like this:

public class MyFirstProvider extends ContentProvider {

```
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 7;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myxdb.db";
public static final String TABLE_PLANING = "planing";
...
static final String URLX = "content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/planing";
...
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_PLANING = Uri.parse(URLX);
...
static final int uriCode = 1; // some table
static final int uriCode52 = 53; // planing
static final int uriCode53 = 54; // planing

static final UriMatcher uriMatcher;
private static HashMap<String, String> values;
static {
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "planing", uriCode52);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "planing/*", uriCode53);
    ...
}

....

 @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String where, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        Cursor c;
        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case uriCode:
                qb.setTables(TABLE_NAME);
                qb.setProjectionMap(values);
                c = qb.query(db, projection, where, selectionArgs, null,null, sortOrder);
                break;
            ...
            default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("(qry)Unsupported URI: " + uri);
    }
    if (c != null){
       c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    }
    return c;
}
```

So how do I implement your idea in my above approach? I mean how do I declare the uriCode for my union grouped complex query?

Comment: Hey rawQuery require two parameter one your complex query and another is argument . create your own custom query which you will showcase above with ? And pass parameter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136688/sqlite-select-query-with-rawquery-at-android .

Comment: Please this is not my job to add your query diy .

Comment: I really think you missunderstood my question... If you look at it again you will notice that I already have the code to obtain a cursor for a regular query (even using the where clause). So that is not my problem. Also using a rawquery is not an issue either. My issue is how to implement a cursor using the `query` approach for a UNION-ed grouped select statement. I pasted above the skeleton of my ContentProvider so that you or anyone else who wants to help me, would be able to indicate where to add and what to add. I did not find any examples anywhere about doing UNION without rawQuery

Comment: It is not your job to do anything. If you want to help me, please do so. If not, then thank you for your time.

Comment: K sorry for misunderstood . even I don't know how to do it I always use rawQuery when comes to complex query . please post your ans when you solve this issue .sorry again .

Comment: It's ok. Let's hope somebody else who has done this before will join here and shine a light on this matter. It is annoying that a matter so trivial is not explained thoroughly anywhere... It is advertised to use query instead of rawquery, but if you want to use it... then figure it out on your own how to do it... Really annoying. I will post the full answer here in case I can solve it

Comment: There is a similar question that drives me in the right direction, however, it is missing some essential code. Here it is:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949042/union-of-tables-with-cursor-in-android . So the missing code is the part that shows me the uriMatcher part where the URI is added for the unioned query... Any ideas?

Comment: i think he using build query using buildunionQuery and at last using rawQuery :-)

Comment: Yes he is using that, and that is great. However the hidden part (that I am interested in) is the part where he declares his URI for the unioned query for the uriMatcher...

Answer (score 0):

use rawquery in content provider class where you override query method pass necessary  column in query method with uri .
and in provider class match appropriate uri and execute your raw query method you already have db object out there.

> getActivity().getContentResolver().query(MyFirstProvider.CONTENT_URI_RSLDTL,
>   col, where, null, null);

where you can retrive col and where in override query methods parameter .

```
public class ExampleProvider extends ContentProvider {
....
    public Cursor query(
            Uri uri,
            String[] projection,
            String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs,
            String sortOrder) { ...
            /*
             * Choose the table to query and a sort order based on the code returned for the incoming
             * URI. Here, too, only the statements for table 3 are shown.
             */
            switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {

                  break;

                default:
                ...
                    // If the URI is not recognized, you should do some error handling here.
            }
             /*
         * Gets a writeable database. This will trigger its creation if it doesn't already exist.
         *
         */
        db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        //execute raw query
        db.rawQuery(...);

        }
```

Comment: If I do that I can then access the cursor just like a regular simple cursor? How do I include in the rawquery the `where` clause and the `order by` clause that will be issued from the query approach? Also how do I declare the uri for my uriMatcher?

Comment: I will make an edit to my question to describe my current approach for the ContentProvider. Please check that and update your answer accordingly

Comment: or you can use  buildUnionQuery method of SQLiteQueryBuilder

Comment: see my edit you can get where  clause in content provider override method parameter . or you can create custom uri for groupby field and extract it when needed .

Comment: I know how to add the where clause in the query syntax. My question was about adding the where clause to the rawquery inside my override of the query inside the ContentProvider. Please check out my EDIT of the question to see my ContentProvider, and please explain how should I update my query implementation in it. Thank you

Comment: Bare in mind that I am relatively new to this, and I learn a lot by example. So code would help me more than refferences to documentation. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any way to use a `query` instead of `rawquery` when you want to do a UNION query.

I'm brought to think it doesn't currently exist by the fact that `SQLiteQueryBuilder` class contains methods to build a UNION query, but it doesn't contain any method to execute it, and I wouldn't expect to find it anywhere else.

More specifically, if you look at [`SQLiteQueryBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html) class, you'll find that [`buildUnionQuery`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#buildUnionQuery(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method returns a `String` and there's no `query` method that takes a custom query String as a parameter.

That said, the solution I adopted in my code is this:

Inside your `query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)` switch statement...

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
builder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);
HashSet<String> columnsPresentInTable = new HashSet<>(<columns in your table>);
String firstProjection = "shop, target as Ian, 0 as Feb, 0 as Mar, 0 as Apr, 0 as Mai, 0 as Iun, 0 as Iul, 0 as Aug, 0 as Sep, 0 as Oct, 0 as Noi, 0 as Decu";
String firstSelectSubQuery = builder.buildUnionSubQuery(
        null,
        firstProjection,
        columnsPresentInTable,
        0,
        getType(uri),
        selection,
        new String[]{
            String.valueOf(2015),
            String.valueOf(1)
        },
        null
);
[...]
String lastProjection = "shop, 0 as Ian, 0 as Feb, 0 as Mar, 0 as Apr, 0 as Mai, 0 as Iun, 0 as Iul, 0 as Aug, 0 as Sep, 0 as Oct, 0 as Noi, target as Decu";
String lastSelectSubQuery = builder.buildUnionSubQuery(
        null,
        lastProjection,
        columnsPresentInTable,
        0,
        getType(uri),
        selection,
        new String[]{
            String.valueOf(2015),
            String.valueOf(12)
        },
        null
);
String unionQuery = builder.buildUnionQuery(
        new String[]{
            firstSelectSubQuery,
            [...]
            lastSelectSubQuery
        },
        sortOrder,
        null
);
cursor = db.rawQuery(unionQuery, null);
```

This approach can seem to you a little more tricky than just `rawQuery` and maybe not the answer to your question, but I'm using it and recommending it anyway for two reasons: because when there's a method to do something I always prefer to use it, and because I believe it allows me to support future modifications, for example if a query approach is implemented, with minimum effort.